# How to use a model in layoutpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a menu which is shown when the user is logged in.. the code is something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
     @if(Model.IsUserLogged){
     //some html
     }

     @RenderBody()

     @if(Model.IsUserLogged){
     //some html again
     }
</body>
</html>
```

but in layout page I can't use a model, so, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps don't do this in the main layout page, create partial views which can use a model, and include them in places where you wish to display conditional output.

Comment: Thanks. but how can I pass a model to a partialView is the layout page do not have one model? and how can I receive a model which I posted like the login of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this that involves using a partial view, although you'd need to move your logic there and out of the layout. Create a partial view (say, "_MyMenu" or whatever), place your rendering logic there, create a controller method for it:

```
public PartialViewResult MenuView() {
    SomeObject model = GetSomeObject()
    return PartialView("_MyMenu", model);
}
```

Then in your layout page, call it with `RenderAction`:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MenuView", "MyController");}
```

Someone already mentioned how to obtain the user's authentication state, so I'm not sure if that's enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

If it is authorization or authentication information you are looking for why not read from Request or cookies.  For example above:

```
@Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Other small amounts of user data could be stored in a cookie and read using a helper.  Or you could have much more user data in local storage if your audience browsers could support it.

Comment: 'IsUserLogged' is just one of the many others properties that I need, for example a string for search but thanks.

Comment: @murilokunze like i say, if these are user settings think about storing them in a cookie or local storage (loading them once on login)